# What is the right way of using c++ stl iterators instead of traditional pointers?

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following very basic question. I want to use stl iterators instead of traditional C-type pointers for filling an array in a function. By the C-style way I mean the following example:

```
void f(double* v, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
         v[i] = 10;    /* a more reasonable value in practice! */
}
```

I would convert this to the C++ style using the iterators as follows:

```
void f(vector<double>::const_iterator first, vector<double>::const_iterator last) {
    for(vector<double>::iterator it =  first; it != last; it++)
        *it = 10;
}
```

But I get compilation errors. If I use `iterator` instead of `const_iterator` the problem will be solved. However, I was wondering if that is the correct way? Because I thought `vector.begin()` and `vector.end()` iterators are constant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using `const_iterator` if you are not modifying what the iterator is pointing to, otherwise, you should use `iterator`

Comment: I imagine `first` would be modified but not the `last`, so should I use `const_iterator` only for the `last` argument?

Is the way I am writing the code generally correct?

Comment: No, I would keep the start and end iterators as the same type.

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi It's not about modifying `first` or `last`, it's about modifying what they point to, which you obviously do when setting the values to `10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between

```
const vector<double>::iterator
```

and

```
vector<double>::const_iterator
```

is roughly the same as between `double * const v` and `const double *v`:

- the first says that the iterator must remain constant, but what it points to can be changed
- the second says that the iterator itself is changeable, but what it points to is `const`.

If you rewrite the function as

```
void f(const vector<double>::iterator first, const vector<double>::iterator last) {
    for(vector<double>::iterator it =  first; it != last; it++)
        *it = 10;
}
```

it would compile and run correctly.

Comment: If you wrote `vector<double>::iterator const`, the parallel with `ddouble *const` would be clearer.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is due to the fact that `const_iterator`'s correspond roughly to pointers to const. So you can change the value of the iterator, i.e. make it point somewhere else, but you cannot modify what it points to.

This is different from const iterators, which would not allow incrementing or decrementing them. Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };

  std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin();
  *i = 10;                                         // ERROR!
  ++i;                                             // OK

  std::vector<int>::iterator const ci = v.begin();
  *ci = 10;                                        // OK
  ++ci;                                            // ERROR!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::fill(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `const_iterator`s, you can't modify the vector.  Using non-const `iterator`s is the right thing to do.

In answer to your last question, `vector.begin()` and `vector.end()` have both `const_` and non-`const_` implementations.  If your vector is non-const, you'll get a non-`const_` iterator.  See the documentation for [std::vector::begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your functions takes `const_iterator`s but your loop needs an `iterator`, since you want to modify the data. The solution is of course to let your function take `iterator`s right away, since it is obviously meant to modify the range.

This doesn't have anything to do with what `vector.begin()` returns. For a `const` object or reference they will return `const_iterator`s, otherwise they'll return `iterator`s. But your function definitely needs `iterator`s, since it modifies the values in the range passed to it.